# Ckeckebale box in ListActivity

Tags: android

I Want to select various dishesh from MenuCard Activity
Here is my ProductAdapter

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



 import com.beans.Product;
 import com.vinayak.hk.MenuCard;
 import com.vinayak.hk.R;

 public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

ArrayList<Product> allProducts;
LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;


public ProductAdapter (Context context , int resource ,ArrayList<Product> objects)
{
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    allProducts = objects;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position ,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = convertView;
        if(v==null)
        {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);

        holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        holder.price = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.price);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cb1);


        v.setTag(holder);

    }

    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

    }

    //holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    holder.name.setText(allProducts.get(position).getProduct_name());



    int s = allProducts.get(position).getProduct_price();
    //Log.d("********************",Integer.toString(s));
    holder.price.setText(Integer.toString(s));

    //final ListView lv = (ListView) parent;
    //holder.checkbox.setChecked(lv.isItemChecked(position));

    //holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);


    return v;

}

static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView name;
    public TextView price;
    public CheckBox checkbox ;


}






 }
```

And my ListActivity is:

MenuCard.java

```
 public class MenuCard extends ListActivity {

ListView list;
Button btn1;
String url="";
private ArrayList <Product>  allProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();
private ProductAdapter adapter;
public static boolean[] arrBoolean = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_card);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    list = getListView();
    Bundle d = getIntent().getExtras();

    url="http://10.0.2.2:8084/Hotelkart/Product?id="+d.getInt("id");


    try{
        ConnectivityManager c =(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);                  
        NetworkInfo n =c.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (n!= null && n.isConnected()){





            Log.d("url*********",url);

            new Background().execute(url);
        }
       }catch(Exception e){}




    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 adapter = new  ProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.productrow,allProducts);

  setListAdapter(adapter);
  list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
  btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();;



    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> selectedItemsPrice = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> selectedItemsId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Log.d("**************",Integer.toString(checked.size()));
    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
        // Item position in adapter
        int position = checked.keyAt(i);
        // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
        if (checked.valueAt(i))
            {
            selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position).getProduct_name());
                selectedItemsPrice.add(adapter.getItem(position).getProduct_price());
            selectedItemsId.add(adapter.getItem(position).getProduct_id());
            }
    }

    int k = selectedItems.size();
    int[] outputStrArrId = new int[k];
    int[] outputStrArrPrice = new int[k];
    String[] outputStrArrItem = new String[k];



    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        outputStrArrItem[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
        outputStrArrId[i] = selectedItemsId.get(i);
        outputStrArrPrice[i] = selectedItemsPrice.get(i);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddOrder.class);

    // Create a bundle object
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray("st3", outputStrArrItem);

    b.putIntArray("st1",outputStrArrId );
    b.putIntArray("st2",outputStrArrPrice );
    // Add the bundle to the intent.
    intent.putExtras(b);

    // start the ResultActivity
    startActivity(intent);




}
});


}
```

but i get an error at

```
  02-01 00:39:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1619): java.lang.NullPointerException
  02-01 00:39:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):   at  com.vinayak.hk.MenuCard$1.onClick(MenuCard.java:95)
  02-01 00:39:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
  02-01 00:39:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
  02-01 00:39:08.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
```

I have problem retriving checked item
when i press btn1 i get above message
on ***************

```
 for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++)
```

.Please help me,

Comment: when you get this error ? when you click on check box or etc ?

Comment: when i click on button

Comment: do you have checked item or no item is checked ?

Comment: i checked dishes and then click on button

Comment: checking `checked != null` with an `if` before your `for` will resolve the error but im not sure why its null

Comment: can you suggest similar program,so i can make case study

Comment: you have a great answer now :) try ρяσѕρєя K answer

Answer (score 1):

Getting `NullPointerException` because `getCheckedItemPositions()` return `null` because you are using custom layout for ListView and customized `ArrayAdapter` for creating ListView row.

To get all checked item from ListView:

**Option 1.** Use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` layout and default ArrayAdapter implementation :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                            <price_list>);
```

and make sure `choiceMode` mode is enabled in ListView using `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"`

Now use `getCheckedItemPositions()` to get set of checked items in the list.

**Option 2.** if custom layout and adapter is necessary for application then  customize `ProductAdapter` to save and retrieve checked checkbox positions.

See following example:
 [Implement custom multi select ListView with custom ArrayAdapter](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/11/implement-custom-multi-select-listview.html)